# Set boilerplate code in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

How do I set a boilerplate code for Python files in PyCharm? I have a set of comments that I need to add at the start of every file I author. It looks something like this-

```
# Author: El Salvador Bali
# Project: American Indo
# Date Created: 2000BC
# Objective: have fun
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `File and Code Templates` (`File - Settings - Editor - File and Code Templates - Python Script`). [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/file-and-code-templates.html) is the help page.